# Какой алгоритм использовать для задачи?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Я прошу только алгоритм, которым пользоваться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты скопируй задание текстом и вставь сюда, а не скриншотом.

Comment: у меня сейчас только скриншот

Comment: Сначала найдем сумму всех элементов. Поделим на количество. Таким образом получаем среднее значение, на которое надо заменить все элементы. Если сумма элементов не делится на количество, сразу выводим -1. Идем по массиву. Если элемент больше или равен среднему, то пропускаем его. Если он меньше среднего, то нам надо дополнить его до среднего. И для этого надо как-то найти ближайший элемент слева который больше среднего и справа. И изменить элементы. Но я не знаю как это быстро делать =( Возможно тут надо использовать структуры данных типа дерева отрезков.

Comment: Кстати интересно, что теоретически условие не запрещает вообще удалять крайние столбцы, нет?

Comment: @Harry количество столбцов менять нельзя

Comment: @Harry я написала программу, но в проверяющей системе она не проходит один из тестов (не используя функцию, что снизу)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
lt find_way(lt n,vector<lt>& pt){

    if(n == 1) return 0;
    lt b = 0;
    lt i = 0;
    lt j = 0;
    lt k = 0;
    lt left = 0;
    lt right = 0;
    while(b != n){

       // print(pt);
        i = find_min(pt); //index
        j = find_max(pt);

        if(i != j){
            pt[j]--;
            if(i < j){
                j--;
            }
            else{
                j++;
            }
            pt[j]++;

            swap(left,right);
            if(left == pt[i] && right == pt[j]){
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else{
            return k;
        }

        left = pt[i];
        right = pt[j];
        k++;
        b = proverka(pt); //counting p[0] == p[i]
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Как следует не тестил, так что могут быть ошибки...

Comment: Какие библиотеки кроме вектора вы использовали? Если я правльно понимаю это фнкция? Что значит It?

Comment: using lt = long int; Кроме vector'а больше ничего не использовал.Да я дал вам функцию в которую входят другие функции (подписал что они делают).